# JS Date calculator of delta time betwen a user entered date and today's date

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, user-input, calculator

The project's idea is simple: A calculator that retrieves input from a user, hopefully in a date-time format although I don't know how to do that so I am for now retrieving integers and constructing a date out of them, and it subtracts the today's date giving me the number of days left until said entered date. Yeah, it may be simple but I have no idea what I am doing wrong as of right now I get as a value in my HTML NaN. So once again to be clear, the user enters a date and JS will calculate how many days are until that said date. Please help me as little as you can, any little help matters to me.

This is the code I Have so far:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var y = prompt("Enter the year")
var yy = prompt("Enter the month")
var yyy = prompt("Enter the day")
today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
var oneDate = new Date(y, yy, yyy);
var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((oneDate - today) / oneDay));
document.write(diffDays)
```

Comment: Dates are in general hard to work with in js. Most ppl end up using helper libraries for date manipulation. The most popular library being [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), however there is this "new" alternative library called [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) that you might want to use instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually very close. You re–assign a string to *today* for no reason, just keep it as a Date. But since you want whole days, you need to zero the time.

Also, subtract 1 from *yy* as it will be the calendar month number, not ECMAScript month number, so:

```js
var today = new Date();
// zero the time
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var y = prompt("Enter the year")
var yy = prompt("Enter the month")
var yyy = prompt("Enter the day")
// don't do this
//today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
const oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
// Subtract 1 from month number
var oneDate = new Date(y, yy - 1, yyy);
var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((oneDate - today) / oneDay));

document.write(diffDays)
```

Comment: The correct answer from 2020/1/1, rounded to 0 decimal places is currently 176. See my working code below using dayjs. This code gives 206,

Comment: @JoshWulf—then your answer is wrong. Adding all month days to 2020-07-25 is 31+29+31+30+31+30+25 = 207. Subtract 1 for 1 Jan gives 206. 176 is out by 30 days, so you've likely not accounted for calendar vs ECMAScript month number. `new Date(year, month, day)` should be `new Date(year, month - 1, day)` unless the user should enter the ECMAScript month number (so 0 for January).

Comment: Right on, thanks. I updated my snippet so it gives the correct output.

Comment: @RobG ey silly me, well thanks a lot now I understand where I was wrong :3 Thanks a lot for the time spent

Answer (score -1):

You can do this easily using the [Dayjs](https://day.js.org/en/) library. It is only 2KB, so it won't make your page that much bigger, but it will make your life a lot simpler.

Here is a fully working example for the browser:

```js
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_duration)
dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_relativeTime)
  
const now = dayjs();

const year = prompt("Enter the year");
const month = prompt("Enter the month");
const day = prompt("Enter the day");

const userDate = dayjs(new Date(year, month - 1, day));

const difference = dayjs.duration(now.diff(userDate)).asDays();

document.write(`${Math.round(difference, 0)} days`);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.30/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.30/plugin/relativeTime.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.30/plugin/duration.js"></script>
```

Comment: There are any number of ways to rewrite the code using a library (or not), but that doesn't help the OP to understand why their code doesn't do what they expect.